# d3.js not reading JSON (d3.js + dc.js + crossfilter)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to visualize some data with d3.js + dc.js + crossfilter.
I am using a JSON file where data are stored.
But it looks like d3 is not reading the data.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the error: d3.js:8756 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "Mundefined,6V0Hun…".

Here the code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<link href="frameworks/dc.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" 
integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.12/ 
crossfilter.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.5/dc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://rawgit.com/crossfilter/reductio/master/reductio.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://npmcdn.com/universe@0.8.1/universe.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chart1"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
<div id="chart3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index_json.js"></script>



</body>
<footer>    



</footer>
</html>
```

JS

```
window.onload=function(){

var colorScale = 

d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["name","total","category"]) 
.range(["#006699","#33F5B7", "#6CD4FF", "4DE6D8" ]);


var data; 
d3.json("./pata.json", function(data) {

console.log(data[1]);
var ndx = crossfilter(data);


var nameDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
return d.nome; 
});  
var croccDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
return d.croccantezza; 
});  
var gustoDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
return d.gusto; 
});  
var chimDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
return d.chimichevolezza; 
});  
var dipDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
return d.rischio_dipendenza; 
});  


var nameSumGroup = nameDim.group().reduceSum(function(data){ return 
d.total; });
var croccGroup = croccDim.group();
var gustoGroup = gustoDim.group();
var chimGroup = chimDim.group();
var dipGroup = dipDim.group();var chart1 = dc.barChart("#chart1");
chart1

.width(400).height(200)
.dimension(croccDim)
.group(croccGroup)
.brushOn(true)
.yAxisLabel("Quantity of Records")
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.colors(colorScale);




var chart2 = dc.barChart("#chart2");
chart2

.width(400).height(200)
.dimension(gustoDim)
.group(gustoGroup)
.brushOn(true)
.yAxisLabel("Sum of Totals")
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 60})
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.colors(colorScale);



var catChart = dc.pieChart("#chart3");
catChart
.width(200).height(200)
.radius(80)
.innerRadius(20)
.dimension(dipDim)
.group(dipGroup)
.colors(colorScale);


dc.renderAll();

});

}
```

JSON

```
{"Patatine":[

{"nome":"Fonzies", "croccantezza":"9", "gusto":7, 
"rischio_dipendenza":10, "chimichevolezza":5},
{"nome":"Yonkers", "croccantezza":"6", "gusto":10, 
"rischio_dipendenza":9, "chimichevolezza":9},
{"nome":"SanCarlo1933", "croccantezza":"10", "gusto":7, 
"rischio_dipendenza":8, "chimichevolezza":3},
{"nome":"Pringles", "croccantezza":"7", "gusto":8, 
"rischio_dipendenza":7, "chimichevolezza":9},
{"nome":"Dixi", "croccantezza":"6", "gusto":8, 
"rischio_dipendenza":10, "chimichevolezza":6},
{"nome":"BBacon", "croccantezza":"7", "gusto":10, 
"rischio_dipendenza":10, "chimichevolezza":9},
{"nome":"Virtual", "croccantezza":"8", "gusto":9, 
"rischio_dipendenza":8, "chimichevolezza":8}


]}
```

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3u40ox7u/4/
Anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: Could you include your code in a `javascript/html/css snippet`? This way we could reproduce your error. For now I can't make it work due to a lot of errors some of which due to dependencies and none of which are your error.

Comment: @XavierGuihot thanks! I've added a JS Fiddle!

Comment: What about `index_json.js` and `index.css`?

Comment: index.css was an old css...useless...index.json.js is the code in the js section @XavierGuihot

Comment: Did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

You can replace this part of the code:

```
var data; 
d3.json("./pata.json", function(data) {
  console.log(data[1]);
  var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

with:

```
d3.json("./pata.json", function(data) {
  console.log(data.Patatine);
  data = data.Patatine
  var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

---

The error

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "Mundefined,6V0Hun…".
```

comes from the way you read the json file.

In fact, just above your error, in the console, you probably see this:

```
undefined
```

which comes from `console.log(data[1]);` in:

```
var data; 
d3.json("./pata.json", function(data) {
  console.log(data[1]);
```

The data of interest in your json (the list) is in fact `data.Patatine`. And thus to print `data[1]` you should in fact use `data.Patatine[1]`